# appium | python | ios | wait_activity function is not working in iOS

Tags: python-appium

I'm trying to use this Explicit wait instead of `sleep(15)`

```
self.driver.wait_activity(locators.skip, 15, .5)
```

But appium is complaining that this function is not implemented for iOS.

Which function should I use for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)`
will solve all this issue, and if you're using a while loop, or try except, etc etc, you also need to use it inside those methods.
I used it in setup class and I need not to repeat the same code at every element.